# Android show multicolor progress bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, progress-bar, swiperefreshlayout

how can I show the multicolor progress bar seen on almost all google apps, which pops down from the ActionBar and changes color every time it rotates once? I know you can use `SwipeRefreshLayout` but I don't think this will work in my case.

I am using a google map which displays the position of buses (they get loaded from a webserver). I already have a refresh menu button in the ActionBar but would like to display that circle loading progress bar above the map when I click the menu button.

Comment: SwipeRefreshLayout is the correct one

Comment: See question. I don't think this will work, because I am displaying a  map in it.

Comment: oh got it. So you want only the drawable without the gesture ?

Comment: When I press the refresh menu button in the actionbar the progress drawable should pop down like it would do in a SwipeRefreshLayout, but without using one

Comment: I was looking at the code of SwipeRefreshLayout. Internally the use `MaterialProgressDrawable`. The member is private and the class is annotated with @hide, so you can't access it directly. But you can try to understand how does it work

Comment: I don't think I understand android that good to find out how that works, sorry!